# What diagnostic tools are available on fully updated Windows 10 Mobile Nokia/Windows Lumia 950XL Phone?

Tags: lumia-950-xl

I'm experiencing challenges on my Lumia 950XL. Getting silly now due to no dynamic Microsoft support. I need to diagnose my camera(s). My video no longer functions (no called parties 'see' me) using both WhatsApp & Skype. I thought it might be due to an application update issue. I'm running up-to-date variants. Finally an epiphany perhaps my camera is screwed. I can take photos of items fine, but no possiblilty to swap cameras. Possibility the User-Facing camera's been inadvertently disabled?